# Check for a new month using Date in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I would like to notify the user and reset an aspect of the app once a new month begins. This reset needs to repeats every time the month changes.

Using Swift and have used the DateToolsSwift pod.[Date Pod](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)

What's the best way to get this to work

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code that we can help you with?

Comment: @fuzz I was thinking of using userDefaults every time the app launches to check the current date with the last saved date and if the month is different then action the reset on the app. But I prefer not to use user defaults, so hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `UserDefaults`? You want to save a little piece of state, and that API is perfect for that. Manually persisting a file somewhere is another alternative, you could bring big guns that are not worth it for this task (Core Data), etc.

Comment: @gg11 I suggest you give that a go and if you're having trouble implementing it then you can always edit your question and we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
func checkIfNewMonth(newDate: Date, oldDate: Date){

    var userCalendar = Calendar.current
    userCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!

    let oldComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: oldDate)
    let newComponents = userCalendar.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: newDate)

    guard let oldCompareDate = userCalendar.date(from: oldComponents) else { return }
    guard let newCompareDate = userCalendar.date(from: newComponents) else { return }

    if newCompareDate > oldCompareDate {
        //New date is a new month
    } else if newCompareDate < oldCompareDate {
        //New date is an previous month
    }
}
```

Thought I'd post a function that does what the op asked.  Just feed in the two dates you want to compare.  I think UserDefaults would be a great way of storing the old date as well.

Answer (score 0):

The calendar [can tell you the range of the current month](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292908-dateinterval).  The next month begins at the end of the current month:

```
let startOfNextMonth = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .month, for: Date())?.end
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
print(startOfNextMonth.map(formatter.string(from:)) ?? "not a date")
```

Simply schedule a [UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest) for this date.